# Ubuntu 12.04 x86 inside vmware workstation 8

Tags: 12.04, vmware

I'm trying to install ubuntu 12.04 x86 inside vmware workstation 8. However I think the process the stuck. Its just showing "Retrieving file 43 of 105" from the last 45 mins or so.
Is it normal ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't take that long unless your internet connection has dropped (which is hasn't because you're posting here).  So I would start over from scratch, chances are it'll work fine this time.

Comment: I'm installing it on a different machine, which is not connected to internet. Is it necessary to connect to internet for installation ?

Comment: The Internet connection is not required during install. Just be sure to apply the updates after you get it installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start with the "install updates" option? If so, maybe the default Ubuntu servers are under a load at the time and so the updates are coming very slowly. Can you click the details button, then click "skip" button?

Here's how I suggest to install Ubuntu (at least until the rush is over in about 2 months): uncheck "apply updates while installing" and disconnect the network entirely (see picture below). This will ensure the install process completes without waiting on any external servers (I just did it right now in fact, in virtualbox-ose, and it finished the installation in just a few minutes.. maybe I will make a youtube video for it). After that, when Ubuntu is installed and you've restarted, I would "edit" from the software center - the sources from where you download your software - to something faster - in my case it's ubuntu.osuosl.org or samaritan.ucmerced.edu. Here's  where you can see which mirrors are the best: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors
Here's a tip for the Ubuntu developers - have a way for us to select a faster mirror (edit software sources) at this screen.

[image: Quick install method]

Comment: Unfortunately vmware was using the auto install mode.

When I connected tht machine to internet, and started the installation again, it went smooth.

Just still I dont know why it stuck on that file when I was not plugged to internet

Answer (score 0):

Using Vmware you are already connected to internet if Host is connected to internet. I suggest you disconnect 1st and finish installation offline.

Answer (score -2):

While installation it retrives updates from the internet... Even it download updates if you de-selects "Download updates installing installing" & Install this third part software option...

This might help you, check your internet connectivity...

Also, I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS in VMware Workstation 8.0.2 without any issues...

http://mytricks.in/2012/05/guide-how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-lts-in-vmware-workstation-8.html

Comment: No, it won't download updates if you deselects, this is wrong